# STR: Vertical light tube in a train experiment

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

This experimental setup is widely used to derive a formula for time dilation (also all other Lorentz transformations). There is a Pythagorean theorem conveniently waiting to be used.
But I can't understand how it makes sense there. So we have a light emitter at the ceiling and a detector at the floor of a train car. In my version let there will not be any tube. Just emitter and detector. And let emitter emit only one single photon. When it reaches the detector it will light up with its own bulb of light. So what will happen for both observers (inside the car and a stationary)? Since the motion of photon doesn't depend on the motion of the train it will just miss the detector and the bottom bulb will never activated! Unless the train is stationary. What's wrong here?

Comment: Why do you think the photon will miss the detector?

Comment: BTW, the deflection of light in a moving frame was first noticed and measured in the late 1600s, centuries before Einstein's theories of relativity. Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aberration_(astronomy)

Comment: @PM2Ring I guess it will miss the detector because that deflection?

Comment: No. The light travels from the emitter to the detector, and activates the detector. All observers *must* agree on that fact. In the train frame the light path is vertical, in the ground frame the light path is deflected from the vertical.

Comment: I think its vice versa - from platform it's vertical (and miss the detector) and inside the train it's deflected from the vertical (and also miss the detector).

Comment: Does the light hit the detector if the train is stationary?

Comment: Yes,  light hit the detector if the train is stationary.

Comment: .....and the train is always stationary. You can't move with respect to space.

Comment: That's an interesting concept, but I call bs. No Einstein, no Lorentz weren't sure about that (you can google it). No Nobel Prize committee was and isn't up to these days.

Answer (score 2):

If the photon is emitted directly downwards in the frame of the moving train, then it will be moving at an angle to the vertical in the frame of the platform.

ADDENDUM

The OP's comment upon my initial answer shows a fixed belief that light will not travel vertically downwards in the frame of the moving train, which is utterly wrong.

To labour the point, take the case in which the emission of light is from a laser fixed at a height of y=4ft at x=0 on the train, arranged so that the laser points vertically downwards to illuminate a spot on the floor of the carriage (y=0). In the frame of the train, the photons from the laser are traveling vertically downwards. An individual photon takes around 4ns to move from the laser to hit the floor.

Suppose a platform passes the train at 0.5c just as a photon is emitted at time t'=t=0 at a point x'=x=0.

In the frame of the train, the photon moves downwards at 1ft per nanosecond. Its y coordinate reduces by 1ft per nanosecond, while its x coordinate remains unchanged at x=0.

In the frame of the passing platform, however, the constant x=0 coordinate transforms to an x' coordinate that increases by 0.5ft per nanosecond. In the platform frame, the photon is not moving vertically downwards but at an angle. The crude diagram below should hopefully spell it out.

[image]

Comment: You are describing physical body trajectory. If you drop a coin it will hit the spot right under initial position and fall in a vertical straight line for internal observer and for the outside observer it will appear at an angle.

Comment: You are simply wrong to assume that light, in this context, does not behave in that way. I have edited my answer to elaborate upon the point.

Comment: Your pic clearly shows that photon will miss the detector. lol

Comment: I've finished your pic https://ibb.co/bdCrhvP

Comment: No, you misunderstand. The pic shows the reverse situation, in which the laser is emiting the light on the platform and hits the ground vertically below. If you agree that happens, then you must agree that light takes an angled path from the train's perspective. Since motion is relative, the reverse must be true- a light traveling vertically on the train will be travelling at an angle in the frame of the platform.

Comment: Why you positioned emitter outside the train? Also you claim "In the frame of the passing train, however, the constant x=0 coordinate transforms to an x' coordinate that increases by 0.5ft per nanosecond." and not explain this effect. Remember, that we don't have Lorentz transformations yet but trying to derive them from this experiment.

Comment: Please draw the same picture, but when emitter is inside the train.

Comment: Have you ever dealt with time-lapse photography? If the emitter were inside the train, and you had a camera set up on the platform, and then you took a time exposure of the photon as it moved inside the train, it would trace out a line of light that is not vertical, but at an angle.

Comment: @Evan and this effect does not apply to the theory of relativity whatsoever. Also by the condition of this sample we have only one photon which can trace only one dot.

Comment: I have changed the scenario and diagram so it now matches your original. The photon is now directed vertically on the train. The point you seem not to grasp is that the photon can either be released vertically in the train, and at an angle on the platform, or vertically on the platform and at an angle on the train. It cannot be moving vertically in both frames.

Comment: I agree, but in this setup it's vertically on the platform and at an angle on the train (while train is moving).

Answer (score 1):

If we have no gravity, and a rock is shot from the ceiling of the train, the train observer sees this velocity vector:
[image]

The observer on the platform sees the rock with an additional component of velocity matching that of the train and sees the diagonal velocity vector, if the train is moving to the right:
[image]

For a photon of light, the train observer sees this:
[image]

While an observer on the platform sees this diagonal vector:
[image]

Comment: According to your image light is indistinguishable from physical body, which is not true, which is the whole point of relativity.

Comment: Look at the difference, the magnitude of the light velocity vector is the same in every frame, consistent with Einstein's postulate/assumption. For the rock, it is different in both frames. Do you see how the light's velocity vectors are swiveled in a circle, while the rock's is not?

Comment: Ok, I got your point. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The easies thing to do is look at 4-wave vector in the (x-direction) moving frame:

$$ k'_{\mu} \equiv (\frac{\omega'}c, \vec k')=(k', 0,0,k')$$

and Lorentz transform is back to the stationary frame:

$$ k_{\mu} = (\frac{\gamma\omega'+\beta\gamma k'_xc}c,
\beta\gamma\omega'/c+\gamma k'_x,k'_y,k'_z)
$$

$$ k_{\mu} =(\gamma k', \gamma\beta k',0, k')$$

so it moves at the approximate angle to hit the detector. (You can transform the events of emission and absorption  to show this).

If you are using laser pulses, remember that $k_{\mu}$ is orthogonal to lines of constant phase:

$$ \phi(x^{\mu})=k_{\mu} x^{\mu}=\omega t-\vec k \cdot \vec x$$

The lines are parallel to $x'$ at constant $t'$. When that is transformed to the stationary frame, lines at constant $t$ are tilted and are not  parallel to $x$.

In other words, the boost puts a phase ramp across the front of the laser, and it no longer exits perpendicular to the aperture.

(Since photons bounce up and down many times in a laser cavity, and moving lasers work, it should be obvious that moving mirrors break $\theta_r=\theta_i$.)

Note that the idea that the light must move along $z''$ in any frame that is boosted along $\pm x'$, which is the premiss of the question, is contrary to relativity. It assigns a natural rest frame to the photon (or light wave), that forever remembers the reference frame of the emitter.

Comment: Are you kidding me? Train example is used to *derive* Lorentz transformations, not vice versa. Also tilted trajectory is a trajectory of a physical body, see my comment to another answer.

Comment: So why doesn't the motion of the photon depend on the motion of the train? That's where your whole argument comes....off...the...rails.

Comment: Please point me where STR says that the light affected by the motion of the emitter (or any other waves btw).

Comment: Where did I say light was effected by the motion of the emitter?

Comment: You said "why doesn't the motion of the photon depend on the motion of the train?" which means exactly "photon depends on the motion of the train" which is false.

Comment: The second postulate of relativity is that the *speed* of light is independent of the motion of the source. This is not at all the same as saying that the *motion* of the light is independent. The first postulate of relativity (that there is no absolute motion) refutes that: there is no way to tell whether a train is moving or not in any absolute sense.

Comment: It's completely explained in my answer already. But it OP declares it false with no explanation, then there's no way to make progress. Photons don't care, but moving lasers/antennas have titled phase front and do not emit radiation orthogonal to their apertures. It's not the light that changes, it's the coordinates that define simultaneous phase that change.

Comment: @EricSmith "This is not at all the same as saying that the motion of the light is independent" - what do you mean? What motion is except velocity and direction? There is no any momentum for light as it has no mass. "the speed of light is independent of the motion of the source" is the sole reason why you can see doppler effect: because emitter shoot the next photon _closer_ to previous one, because it's position _shifted_ towards it (or away from it) because of the motion of the source. For the same reason photon will miss the floor detector in my example.

Comment: @JEB "But it OP declares it false with no explanation" - please, see my comment above (about doppler effect).

Comment: "velocity" is direction and speed. The speed of the emitted light is independent of the speed of the source; but the *direction* of the emitted light does depend on the speed and direction of the source. See for example Evan's diagram above. The Lorentz transformations have been amply verified by experiment. (Incidentally, light certainly does have momentum, and again this is easily verified by experiment.)

Comment: @EricSmith so the motion of the source really changes the vector of the light propagation? That's definitely "particle" part of photons nature. Because waves don't behave like that, waves don't "know" about movement and they don't even "move", they're oscillating (of something).

Comment: I think you need to update your understanding of wave mechanics. The motion of the source relative to the medium does affect the motion of waves (e.g. the bow wave of a ship). Wave mechanics were well understood in the late 19th century, but the null result of the Michelson-Morley experiment (trying to detect the relative motion of the Earth and the hypothetical aether) was still a big surprise.

Comment: @m8labs you're just arguing in circles, and getting no where. Your photon explanation of Doppler is  wrong, and your understanding of waves is lacking. The only Lorentz scalar in a wave is the phase, $\phi$. Take a plane wave and transform the phase. Find the relation between $\vec x$ and $t$ that gives constant phase fronts. Propagation will be orthogonal to that per $k_{\mu}=\partial_{\mu}\phi$. Get it? the wave's not changing, space and time are.

Comment: @EricSmith The motion of the source relative to the medium affects the motion of waves? Are you arguing for the existence of the aether? Perhaps update your understanding of special relativity, to paraphrase the kid from The Matrix: "There is no medium".  I'll say it for the fourth time: phase is a Lorentz invariant, but simultaneity is not, hence: simultaneous phase fronts MUST BE DIFFERENT in different frames.

Comment: @JEB no, I was trying to point out to the OP that they're totally off track: *even if* light were waves in a medium it still wouldn't act the way they were arguing it would.

Comment: @EricSmith But light is a wave without medium. Right? That's what differ it from other waves.

Comment: You need to use "@", then. Otherwise, this thread is going nowhere.  OP refuses to use phase to understand how a wavefront transforms, even though it would be ...wait for it...enlightening.

Comment: @JEB Can you please give a graphical representation of what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

It's not true that the "motion of the train does not affect the motion of the light". The *speed* of the train doesn't affect the *speed* of the light, but motion involves both speed and direction, i.e. it's a vector quantity. Two vectors can have the same length but point in different directions, and that's the case here. Both the observer on the train and the observer on the platform agree on the speed of the light (the magnitude of its velocity vector) but they disagree on its direction. In the frame of the train the light goes straight down. In the frame of the platform the light goes at an angle. In both cases the result is the same, namely that the light hits the detector.

Comment: Coined dropped inside the train behaves exactly like you described, which can't be true unless photon has a mass.

Comment: Why do you think massless objects cannot have different velocity vectors in different frames of reference? Of course in real life they absolutely do. If you perform the experiment of shining a light from ceiling to floor in a real train, the result is not different whether the train is considered "stationary" or "moving". This is the principle of relativity, and dates back to Galileo.

Comment: Because photon is a wave and not an object when it comes to relativity effects.

Comment: So what do you think happens when you shine a laser at a point on a wall across the room from you, when that is presented in terms of a reference frame moving to your left at 0.5c, say? Are you saying that the laser doesn't hit the same spot any more?

Comment: Yes, and this is well known effect as well. If you hold your laser in your hand and wave it, the trace that the beam leave will not be a straight line, but kind of a sin curve. Exactly for the reason of the finite wave velocity and independence of its motion from motion of emitter.

Comment: No. All observers, regardless of their relative motion, must agree where the laser hits the wall, because that's a physical observable. It's a fact of the universe. They can (and will) assign different coordinates to it. To take an extreme example, if you shine a laser out of a small window, all observers will agree that it goes through the window, regardless of how fast they are moving relative to you.

Comment: Were there any experimental proof of this? (I mean similar setup of "laser out of a small window")

Comment: There have been many, many experiments that verify the Lorentz transformations -- in fact there's a whole wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_searches_for_Lorentz_violation

Comment: @m8labs: Multiple people on this thread have tried to explain to you in various different ways why light doesn't act the way you seem to think it does. Here's another way to think: in the modern approach to relativity the special speed $c$ really has nothing to do with any properties of light, because it isn't specific to light: lots of things (light, gravity, gluons, etc.) travel at that speed. The special thing is that all observers agree that *anything* traveling at that speed is always moving at that speed, although they may differ on the directions involved.

Comment: @m8labs: The special speed $c$ is called the "speed of light" for historical reasons, and because light happens (we think) to travel at that speed, but "speed of causality" or "speed of gravity" would be better names.

Comment: @EricSmith I'm not the only one, who is not convinced with any explanations of relativity. Nobel Prize committee wasn't as well. I know that 'speed of light' is the historical name of this thing. This fact doesn't change much for me. "anything traveling at that speed is always moving at that speed" true, but it's about measurements, which are affected by time dilation and length contraction. Yes, I'm not against Lorentz transformations. The way these transformations were derived - that's very questionable for me.

Comment: @m8labs: The Nobel prize commitee apparently has come to its senses since then, having given multiple awards to people for research in relativity. Many Nobel prize winners have worked on relativity and even written textbooks on the subject. Off the top of my head I can name Schroedinger, Dirac, de Broglie, Feynman, Schwinger, Thorne,  Penrose, and Weinberg; I'm sure there are many others. I doubt very much that there is a single prominent physicist of the last century who is "unconvinced" by relativity. Perhaps you think you know physics better than those people, but I know I don't.

Comment: @EricSmith But why STR wasn't given a prize then? Maybe because it's not very good compilation of what _already_ was known at that time? Still a great summary, but with slippery moments here and there and overall not good enough to win a prize...

Answer (score -5):

Consider that there are other explanations not usually discussed.
Then decide which is the most reasonable.

The simplest answer is that the light clock "THOUGHT experiment" relies on a False Dichotomy.  Where the claim is that light can travel two different distances at the same speed but still end up arriving at the one destination at the same instant.

Presumably due to Time warping for some but not others, for no apparent reason.

However, this video link explains clearly why the whole thought experiment is false.
https://vimeo.com/295270284

P.S.  If you want to "down vote" this answer, then at least have the decency to comment on WHY you think the answer is incorrect or failing as a reasonable solution.

Comment: There's no false dichotomy -- light can certainly travel two different distances at the same speed and end up arriving at a destination at the same instant if it starts from two different places. E.g. light from a distant star arriving at a camera at the same time as light from across the room.

Comment: And your comment qualifies as a "Strawman fallacy" argument.  The "experiment" has the condition that the Light ORIGINATED at the same instant, (like the bottom mirror of the Light Clock) AND arrived at the same location at the same instant. (the top mirror of the light clock) So my claim of a False Dichotomy holds true.

Comment: I have downvoted because the video is nonsense. Try working this out for yourself. Suppose the light clock remains stationary, then there is no problem with the photon bouncing between the mirrors - agreed? Now, suppose an observer moves past the stationary light clock- in the observers frame the photon will now be taking a zig-zag path. If you don't understand that then you will never understand SR.